# Setup a Cisco WiFi stick

Tags: networking, wireless, cisco

Previously, when I was using Windows 10, I used a Cisco WiFi stick. Now, I converted to Ubuntu18, I can't find the linked software. The software is is: Linksys, EA 2500, version 1. I've found for Windows, for Mac but none for Ubuntu.

Comment: What makes you believe that a Linux version exists?

Comment: Is it a USB adapter? Please add output of `lsusb` to your question.